# Object.preventExtensions actually allows mutation of __proto__?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming, ecmascript-5

I was browsing MDC about new functions added to Object. One of them, [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions), is said to prevent mutations to the object's prototype, which can be obtained by using `Object.getPrototypeOf` or `__proto__`.

On Chrome, however, it seems to simply allow mutations to the object's prototype. This can be confirmed by just executing the code on the [relevant page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions):

```
// EXTENSION (only works in engines supporting __proto__
// (which is deprecated. Use Object.getPrototypeOf instead)):
// A non-extensible object's prototype is immutable.

var fixed = Object.preventExtensions({});
fixed.__proto__ = { oh: "hai" }; // throws a TypeError
```

I don't get this `TypeError`, and `fixed.__proto__.oh === 'hai'`, so it has been set even though it should have been disallowed. I can also add it when coding like `Object.getPrototypeOf(fixed).oh = 'hai'`.

Does this mean Chrome has a different interpretation of this function? How can one prevent extensions to an object's prototype (in Chrome)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, Chrome and Mozilla both implement the standards part of the spec the same. Read carefully:

> `Object.preventExtensions` only prevents
>   addition of own properties. Properties
>   can still be added to the object
>   prototype.

Everything to do with `.__proto__` is non-standard, and Chrome can implement that differently. You showed only that Chrome implements details with `.__proto__` differently, and in my opinion, more intuitively: The spec says that the prototype **is still extensible**, so it makes sense that you should still be able to mutate it. The question then becomes why did Mozilla implement it *that* way?

For example, the following code works the same on both Chrome and FF:

```
var fixed = Object.preventExtensions({});
Object.getPrototypeOf(fixed).p = 99;
fixed.p; // 99
```

Clearly the prototype is still mutable. That makes sense with Chrome's implementation of `.__proto__`.

So to prevent extensions of a prototype, do so separately:

```
var fixed = Object.preventExtensions({});
Object.preventExtensions(Object.getPrototypeOf(fixed));
Object.getPrototypeOf(fixed).p = 99; // TypeError: Can't add property p, object is not extensible
```

Answer (score 2):

In ECMAScript 5, objects have a boolean [internal property](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.2) named `[[Extensible]]`, this property is set to `false` when you call the [`Object.preventExtensions`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.10) method, and after that, no new **own properties** can be added to the object.

On Chrome 14.0.786.0, the assignment to `__proto__` throws a `TypeError` as you expect.

But remember that the `__proto__` extension is **non-standard**, so it's behavior may vary, of course syntactically it is a "property assignment", but internally it doesn't "add an own property", it mutates the object's prototype, thing that is not possible to do by any standard method.

About the example of the `Object.getPrototypeOf` method you show us, it's simply retrieving the object's prototype, in the case of your `fixed` object, it's the `Object.prototype` object:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(fixed) === Object.prototype; // true
```

So your example:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(fixed).oh = 'hai'
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Object.prototype.oh === 'hai';
```